# Javascript to hit a page for session keepalive, but not change data on open page

Tags: javascript, function, timeout, session-timeout, keep-alive

So I have an edge case that I'm working through in which I have this code to keep a page alive:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    s=self.setInterval("keepSessionAlive()",840000);
});

function keepSessionAlive() {
if (navigator.onLine) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            submitForm();
        }
    };
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/digi/index");
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

The downside to this script is that /digi/index loads a LOT of data from my database.   I want to load an arbitrary page from my domain just for the sake of the keepalive every 14 minutes but not change anything on the display.   The code above updates with any new values, which isn't something I want.

Yay for edge cases...

Thanks